# c SIMD - how do I do memory alignment properly in this case?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, simd, memory-alignment

I have the following two structs in a test program:

```
typedef struct fltptr {
    size_t size;
    float *a;
    float *b;
} fptr;

struct fltWrap256 {
    __m256 *m256;
    __m128 *m128;
    float  *m32;
};

typedef struct fltwrap {
    struct fltWrap256 a;
    struct fltWrap256 b;
} fwrap;
```

The point of 'fwrap' is to give a 'SIMD' way of accessing the equal but variable-size float 'arrays' of a 'fptr' instance. The function **SIMD_point_to( fptr*** **, fwrap*** **)** will point the member pointers of a wrapper instance appropriately:

```
void SIMD_point_to( fptr *v, fwrap *S )
{
    S->a.m256 = (__m256 *)(v->a);
    S->b.m256 = (__m256 *)(v->b);

    uint8_t rem = v->size % 8;
    size_t offset = v->size - rem;
    S->a.m128 = (__m128 *)(v->a + offset);
    S->b.m128 = (__m128 *)(v->b + offset);

    rem %= 4;
    offset = v->size - rem;
    S->a.m32 = v->a + offset;
    S->b.m32 = v->b + offset;
}
```

Visual example:

```
let fptr.a/b = [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]
           m256*^(8x3)        (4x1)m128*^   ^m32*(1x3)

let fptr.a/b = [XXXXX]
      (8x0)m256*^   ^m32*(1x1)
      (4x1)m128*^
```

But because SIMD requires 16-byte alignment I need to use **aligned_alloc( )** when allocating **fptr.x**. At least that's what I think I need to do.

```
int main( )
{
    fptr test;
    //allocated size explicitly a multiple of 16(4x24=96) as required. Working size will be 23 floats.
    test.a = aligned_alloc(16, 16, sizeof(float)*24 );
    test.b = aligned_alloc(16, 16, sizeof(float)*24 );
    test.size = 23;

    /* Filling test.a/b */
    float A[23] = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f, 7.0f, 8.0f, 9.0f, 10.0f, 11.0f, 12.0f, 13.0f, 14.0f, 15.0f, 16.0f, 17.0f, 18.0f, 19.0f, 20.0f, 21.0f, 22.0f, 23.0f };

    float B[23] = { 11.0f, 12.0f, 13.0f, 14.0f, 15.0f, 16.0f, 17.0f, 18.0f, 19.0f, 110.0f, 111.0f, 112.0f, 113.0f, 114.0f, 115.0f, 116.0f, 117.0f, 118.0f, 119.0f, 120.0f, 121.0f, 122.0f, 123.0f };

    memcpy( test.a, A, sizeof(float)*23 );
    memcpy( test.b, B, sizeof(float)*23 );

    fwrap wrap;
    SIMD_point_to( &test, &wrap );

    float __attribute__(( aligned(16) )) out[8];
    /*
    __m256 mout = _mm256_add_ps( wrap.a.m256[0], wrap.b.m256[0] ); //Seg Fault here
    __m256_store_ps( out, mout );
    */
    /*__m256_store_ps( out, wrap.a.m256[1] );*/ //Another here

    __m256_storeu_ps( out, wrap.b.m256[1] ); //THIS WORKS!

    for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
        printf("%f\n", out[i]);
    /*
    out[] contains the second set of 8 floats pointed to by    'wrap.b.m256'.
    */
}
```

**storeu** doesn't throw an error but that just means I'm doing something wrong. Any suggestions?

edit: interestingly compiling with '-O3' (gcc) solves the seg fault at **store** but not **_mm256_add_ps**.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Show full code that reproduces the problem; do not just describe it.

Comment: please paste `SIMD_point_to`

Comment: my bad, see updated op. @tstanisl

Comment: Passing around structs of 3 pointers seems likely to be worse than pointer + length and computing on the fly when you actually want to loop over it, unless you only ever use these for local vars or in things that inline.

Comment: does it work when `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag is added to GCC command line?

Comment: yes, in the real code their main purpose will be to perform parallel vector arihtmetic through inlined functions. At least that's the plan, I am fairly new to these more advanced concepts.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Include the `#include` statements you use so we do not have to guess. Preferably post the code as one sequence, not several scattered through the question that readers have to assemble into one file to compile. Fix the call to `aligned_alloc`; you had two arguments before but now have three. Are you calling `__m256_storeu_ps` or `_mm256_storeu_ps`? My Intel SIMD headers declare the latter but not the former. Ensure the code in the question compiles with no errors or undesired warnings.

Answer (score 1):

From `man aligned_alloc`.

> The function aligned_alloc() is the same as memalign(), except for the added restriction that size should be a multiple of alignment.

I guess that `aligned_alloc` returns `NULL` because `sizeof(float)*23` is not divisible by 16. This causes segfault when pointer is used.

Just round `sizeof(float)*23` to the next multiple of 16.

One way is:

```
(sizeof(float)*23 + 16 - 1) / 16 * 16
```

Other problem is correct alignment of `float out[8];`.
To force the alignment be compatible with `__m256` one can use [_Alignas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas) keyword from C11.

```
_Alignas (__m256) float out[8];
```

---

**Edit**

As suggested in the comment the alignment requirement can be written in a prettier form:

```
#include <stdalign.h>
...
alignas (__m256) float out[8];
```

Comment: ah I neglected to mention in the op that this doesn't solve the problem. Will edit.

Comment: aligned_alloc is not returning NULL either, out[] will contain the first 8 floats of fptr.a when I avoid responsibility with "storeu". The problem is with alignment it seems.

Comment: that will avoid problems down the line so I have edited my code/question accordingly, thanks, but it's throwing a seg fault at '_mm256_add_ps' which doesn't touch out[ ].

Comment: You can also `#include <stdalign.h>` to allow `alignas` (as a #define for _Alignas in C), making your code easily portable to C++.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you only try to align by `16`? `__m256` requires 32-byte alignment

Comment: 32 bytes? This seems to be the case after looking around. I had no idea and assumed a 16-byte requirement across all SIMD registers. It works now!